# Nested functions php

Tags: php, function, nested

I have two classes, Emp and Dep. I want to get a result something familiar to this:

```
$objDep = new Dep();
$objDep->SetName('Sales');

$objEmp = new Emp();
$objEmp->SetDep($objDep);

$objDep->GetEmps()->Add($objEmp);
$objDep->GetEmps(0)->GetDep()->GetName(); //result 'sales'
```

I have written this in Dep class:

```
...
public $_emps = array();
...

...
public function GetEmps() {
        $params = func_get_args();
        $numargs = func_num_args();

        if (func_num_args()) {
            return $this->_emps[$params[0]];
        }

        function Add($new_emp)
        {
            array_push($this->_emps,$new_emp); 
        }

    }
...
```

and a I'm having an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function Add() on a non-object.
```

What is wrong with this code?

Maybe this is simple but I'm new in PHP and I want to complete my exercise for classes.

Comment: You might have meant to use `$objDep->GetEmps(0)->SetDep()->GetName();`? I don't see any other reference to `GetDep()`

Comment: Put `Add` method outside the `GetEmps` method, so its just another method in the class. Emp's and Dep's makes no sense, a good naming convention and class entity would make it clearer to yourself

Comment: Plus, there's no other reference to `GetName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to chain methods, you will want to return `$this`.

Example:

```
public function GetEmps() {
    $params = func_get_args();
    $numargs = func_num_args();

    if (func_num_args()) {
        return $this->_emps[$params[0]];
    }

    return $this;
}

public function Add($new_emp) {
    array_push($this->_emps,$new_emp);

    return $this;
}
```

You may also chain Add, which can result in `$obj->Add($emp1)->Add($emp2)->Add($emp3)->getEmps()`.

You will need to make the function `Add` a member of the class as well.